# unable to insert values in postgresql using PreparedStatement in java from intelliJ

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

i am new to java.i want to insert values into my database(pgadmin) using java.i am using a PreparedStatement but everytime it is giving me an error.The problem seemed to be in the INSERT statement..please help me

```
public void obtaindata(){
        System.out.println("enter the data you want to insert");
        System.out.print("Product Name");
        String productname=input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Product Price");
        Double productprice=input.nextDouble();
        Database2 database2=new Database2();
        database2.insertRecord(productname,productprice);

public void insertRecord(String productname,Double productprice){
        try{
            //using preparedstatement
            PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO  
               public.product(product_id,product_name,product_price)" + 
              "VALUES (?,?,?);"); 
            stmt.setString(1,"nextval('productid_sequence')");
            stmt.setString(2,productname);
            stmt.setDouble(3,productprice);
            stmt.executeUpdate();
            stmt.close();

        }catch(SQLException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: what error??????

Comment: Can you share the error?

Comment: Welcome tp the coffee shop management system
Connection successful
enter the data you want to insert
Product Name Latte
Product Price
2.00
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at Datatypes1.Database2.insertRecord(Database2.java:79)
 at Datatypes1.Database2.obtaindata(Database2.java:69)
 at Datatypes1.Database2.main(Database2.java:14)

Comment: Your code has syntax errors and won't even compile.

Comment: Is the error in the insert statement?

Comment: Did you perhaps trim down your code before posting it? The supplied block doesn't follow correct syntax rules, perhaps review and update the snippet, in its current state it won't compile.

Comment: @TasneemEdoo please edit your question and add error to it.

Comment: Ok thank you will try it!!

Comment: You can't use `stmt.setString(1,"nextval('productid_sequence')");`  like that. You need to put the `nextval()` call into the SQL:  `"VALUES (nextval('productid_sequence'),?,?);`

Comment: I tried it but it didnot work so i put it into setString